# HTML Canvas not playing on mobile devices

Tags: html, canvas, createjs

On all my animate CC projetcs that generate HTML canvas (HTML and JS). They don't play on mobile. Desktop is all OK. I think it is the body onload not being fired. example here: http://creative.super-ideas.co.uk/sheets_www/ani/scale-text.html

I tried to remove the body onload and replace with window onload... but no success.

```js
(function (cjs, an) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
var lib={};var ss={};var img={};
lib.ssMetadata = [];


// symbols:
// helper functions:

function mc_symbol_clone() {
 var clone = this._cloneProps(new this.constructor(this.mode, this.startPosition, this.loop));
 clone.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame);
 clone.paused = this.paused;
 clone.framerate = this.framerate;
 return clone;
}

function getMCSymbolPrototype(symbol, nominalBounds, frameBounds) {
 var prototype = cjs.extend(symbol, cjs.MovieClip);
 prototype.clone = mc_symbol_clone;
 prototype.nominalBounds = nominalBounds;
 prototype.frameBounds = frameBounds;
 return prototype;
 }


(lib.Symbol1 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer_1
 this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
 this.shape.graphics.f("#CC6666").s().p("AjzD0QhlhlAAiPQAAiOBlhlQBlhlCOAAQCPAABlBlQBlBlAACOQAACPhlBlQhlBliPAAQiOAAhlhlg");

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol1, new cjs.Rectangle(-34.5,-34.5,69,69), null);


// stage content:
(lib.scaletext = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer_2
 this.instance = new lib.Symbol1();
 this.instance.parent = this;
 this.instance.setTransform(240,34.5);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).to({y:235.5},22).to({y:34.5},21).wait(1));

 // Layer_1
 this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
 this.shape.graphics.f("#33CCFF").s().p("EglfAVGMAAAgqLMBK/AAAMAAAAqLg");
 this.shape.setTransform(240,135);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(44));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(240,135,240,135);
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
 id: 'C8148930269B47A69483B3EEA7FB2480',
 width: 480,
 height: 270,
 fps: 24,
 color: "#CC3300",
 opacity: 1.00,
 manifest: [],
 preloads: []
};



// bootstrap callback support:

(lib.Stage = function(canvas) {
 createjs.Stage.call(this, canvas);
}).prototype = p = new createjs.Stage();

p.setAutoPlay = function(autoPlay) {
 this.tickEnabled = autoPlay;
}
p.play = function() { this.tickEnabled = true; this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndPlay(this.getTimelinePosition()) }
p.stop = function(ms) { if(ms) this.seek(ms); this.tickEnabled = false; }
p.seek = function(ms) { this.tickEnabled = true; this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndStop(lib.properties.fps * ms / 1000); }
p.getDuration = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).totalFrames / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }

p.getTimelinePosition = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).currentFrame / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }

an.bootcompsLoaded = an.bootcompsLoaded || [];
if(!an.bootstrapListeners) {
 an.bootstrapListeners=[];
}

an.bootstrapCallback=function(fnCallback) {
 an.bootstrapListeners.push(fnCallback);
 if(an.bootcompsLoaded.length > 0) {
  for(var i=0; i<an.bootcompsLoaded.length; ++i) {
   fnCallback(an.bootcompsLoaded[i]);
  }
 }
};

an.compositions = an.compositions || {};
an.compositions['C8148930269B47A69483B3EEA7FB2480'] = {
 getStage: function() { return exportRoot.getStage(); },
 getLibrary: function() { return lib; },
 getSpriteSheet: function() { return ss; },
 getImages: function() { return img; }
};

an.compositionLoaded = function(id) {
 an.bootcompsLoaded.push(id);
 for(var j=0; j<an.bootstrapListeners.length; j++) {
  an.bootstrapListeners[j](id);
 }
}

an.getComposition = function(id) {
 return an.compositions[id];
}


an.makeResponsive = function(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType, domContainers) {  
 var lastW, lastH, lastS=1;  
 window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);  
 resizeCanvas();  
 function resizeCanvas() {   
  var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;   
  var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;   
  var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, sRatio=1;   
  if(isResp) {                
   if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || (respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {                    
    sRatio = lastS;                
   }    
   else if(!isScale) {     
    if(iw<w || ih<h)      
     sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);    
   }    
   else if(scaleType==1) {     
    sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);    
   }    
   else if(scaleType==2) {     
    sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);    
   }   
  }   
  domContainers[0].width = w * pRatio * sRatio;   
  domContainers[0].height = h * pRatio * sRatio;   
  domContainers.forEach(function(container) {    
   container.style.width = w * sRatio + 'px';    
   container.style.height = h * sRatio + 'px';   
  });   
  stage.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;   
  stage.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;   
  lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;            
  stage.tickOnUpdate = false;            
  stage.update();            
  stage.tickOnUpdate = true;  
 }
}


})(createjs = createjs||{}, AdobeAn = AdobeAn||{});
var createjs, AdobeAn;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="authoring-tool" content="Adobe_Animate_CC">
<title>scale-text</title>
<!-- write your code here -->
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script src="scale-text.js"></script>
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, anim_container, dom_overlay_container, fnStartAnimation;
function init() {
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 anim_container = document.getElementById("animation_container");
 dom_overlay_container = document.getElementById("dom_overlay_container");
 var comp=AdobeAn.getComposition("C8148930269B47A69483B3EEA7FB2480");
 var lib=comp.getLibrary();
 handleComplete({},comp);
}
function handleComplete(evt,comp) {
 //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token create_stage.
 var lib=comp.getLibrary();
 var ss=comp.getSpriteSheet();
 exportRoot = new lib.scaletext();
 stage = new lib.Stage(canvas); 
 //Registers the "tick" event listener.
 fnStartAnimation = function() {
  stage.addChild(exportRoot);
  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
 }     
 //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
 AdobeAn.makeResponsive(true,'both',true,1,[canvas,anim_container,dom_overlay_container]); 
 AdobeAn.compositionLoaded(lib.properties.id);
 fnStartAnimation();
}
</script>
<!-- write your code here -->
</head>
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
 <div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00); width:480px; height:270px">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="270" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);"></canvas>
  <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:480px; height:270px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it on my phone, but it seems to work (android 7, chrome). 
Is javascript maybe disabled on your phone?
Did you try to go to settigns on your phone, and click the checkbox with desktop site? It should make your phone make the site load as a desktop, so you can see if the problem is with the mobile version.

Comment: I have javascript enabled... not working for me in ios safari & chrome, good news its working in android.

Comment: After some googling, the only thing I can find is IOS might be resetting the width of the canvas to 0. Can you try to add 
```
canvas.width = '100px';
``
Just after
```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
```

Really uncertain if this should fix the issue for you

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue... it was local to my device, the problem was... I was on a VPN.